# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Module Name'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode in I have a problem importing classes or functions from other files, My directory tree is like this:

```
Engine:
       Functions:
                 EncryptionFunc:
                                Encryption.py
                 SysFunctions.py

       encryption.py
```

and I'm trying to import a function called file_import from SysFunctions.py into Encryption.py lke below:

```
from SysFunctions import file_import
```

also tried these:

```
from Functions.SysFunctions import file_import
from Engine.Functions.SysFunctions import file_import
from rootfolder.Engine.Functions.SysFunctions import file_import
```

none of those works and every folder has init file too

Comment: I think you should move your `SysFunctions.py` to `EncryptionFunc`, and you can do `from SysFunction import file_import`

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

The path of folder `Functions` does not in the `sys.path`(PYTHONPATH).

**Solution:**

You can do this to modify the `PYTHONPATH`:

1. Add these in the settings.json file to Modify the `PYTHONPATH` in the terminal:

   **"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "xxx/Functions"
   }**
2. Create a `.env` file under your workspace, and add these settings in it to modify the `PYTHONPATH` for the extension and debugger:

   **PYTHONPATH=xxx/Functions**

You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) to understand the effects of these two configurations.

3. Modify it directly in the python file. Add these codes in the b.py file.

   **import sys; sys.path.append("xxx/Functions")**

Answer (score 0):

You should move `Encryption.py` to the same level as `SysFunctions.py` or the other way around. Then:

```
from .SysFunctions import file_import
```